# Load only part of <td> into var with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load the value of a  into a variable, but the value has a quite interesting characteristic and I only want the raw number, 1358:

```
<td class="num">&lrm;&#8237;&#8237;1358&#8236;&#8237;&lrm;</td>
```

I've gotten as far as `var lumberSec = $('#production tr:nth-child(1) .num').text()`, but it gives a funky value. Is there any way to only get the value (1358)?

Comment: If you start to look for the funky values it should help you get going: `&lrm;`  is a [left to right mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark#Example_of_use_in_HTML). The next one `‭#8237;` might be a [Unicode Character LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202d/index.htm)

Comment: use regex to extract the number. show us your attempt if still having issues